# Which solution is good to generate a list without None results from a function?

Tags: python, iteration

I'm relatively new to Python and learned, that [function cannot return nothing, not even `None`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32594073/let-a-function-return-nothing-not-even-none-in-python-2-7-10-possible). In my application I want to iterate over a list and keep all non-`None` results of a complicated function:

```
def complicated_function(x):
    if x < 0:
        return "a"
    elif x == 3.6:
        return "b"
    elif x == 4:
        return None  # Idealy here nothing should be returned
    elif x > 10:
        return "c"
    else:
        return "d"
```

I have three soltuions and my question is which would you recommend me to use and are there better ones?

#### First solution

```
tmp = [complicated_function(x) for x in [-1, 2, 3.6, 4, 5, 20]]
ret = [x for x in tmp if x]
```

#### Second solution

```
ret = [complicated_function(x) for x in [-1, 2, 3.6, 4, 5, 20] if complicated_function(x)]
```

#### Third solution

```
ret = []
for x in [-1, 2, 3.6, 4, 5, 20]:
    tmp = complicated_function(x)
    if tmp:
        ret.append(tmp)
```

I think the first solution is slow, if the list to iterate over is very large. The second solution seems to be bad if the complated_function is really expensive (in rumtime). The third solution seems to be ok, but [append is said to be significantly slower than list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245397/why-is-a-list-comprehension-so-much-faster-than-appending-to-a-list).

Comment: Which Python version are you using? In Python 3.8+ you can make your list comprehension less expensive by calling the function only once using the walrus operator.

Comment: @Graipher How would the walrus operator work?

Comment: `ret = [y for x in [-1, 2, 3.6, 4, 5, 20] if (y := complicated_function(x))]`

Comment: @Graipher Thanks for your explanaition of the walrus operator. I'm using Python 3.7, but definitely will keep this in mind as an option when switching to 3.8.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48609910/7311767

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an intermediate generator function:

```
[y for y in (complicated_function(x) for x in <my_iterable>) if y is not None]
```

An alternative is changing `complicated_function` to become a generator that accepts an iterable, instead of a pure function:

```
def complicated_function(iterable):
    for x in iterable:
        if x < 0:
            yield "a"
        elif x == 3.6:
            yield "b"
        elif x == 4:
            continue
        elif x > 10:
            yield "c"
        else:
            yield "d"
```

and then: `list(complicated_function(<my_iterable>))`